# Check if any rows in column in datatable cannot convert from integer to string

Tags: c#, datatable, converters

I have a DataTable which holds scores in one column. The problem is that the score can be an integer or a string, for example, 15 (integer score), or "Advanced" (string score). I don't know what type of scores the column is going to contain, but I want to make a decision after I check whether **any** score in the rows of the column contains a string that cannot convert to an integer. I am using two datatables, one that has the unknown scores (`dt`) and one that will be filled with all the data and scores after I do certain operations (`dtCloned`). I want to convert the datatype of the score column in `dtCloned` before I copy in all the scores by doing these checks: What I want to do is if I have this column with these scores:

```
ScoreValue Column
Advanced
Basic
Proficient
Below Basic
```

If any scores in this column **cannot** convert to an integer (in this case none can) then I do not want to convert the column to an integer datatype, otherwise I do. More examples:

```
Scorevalue column
1
2
3
4
```

This would pass the test because all the values can convert to an integer. It would proceed and convert the column to integer datatype.

```
ScoreValue column
0
Advanced
Proficient
```

This would not pass because there are string values that cannot convert to an integer.
This is what I have so far that just checks if the score in row 10 column 13 (no reason for row 10 just don't know a better way to do this, and column 13 is the score column) can convert to an integer.

```
int number;
bool tryConvert = Int32.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[10][13]), out number);
if (tryConvert)
    dtCloned.Columns[13].DataType = typeof(Int32);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

So, is there any way for me to not have to hard code a specific row number for a check. Ideally **if any row in the column has a string value that cannot convert to an integer do not convert the column data type to integer.** I know that LINQ has a method "Any". Would that work in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `All` will be your friend, as like:

```
int number;
if(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(x => int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(x[13]), out number)))
    dtCloned.Columns[13].DataType = typeof(Int32);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This seems like a real effective solution. Thanks a lot. Never seen All before, definitely always something new to learn with LINQ. Thanks again.